# Is it possible that there is only one patient < 16 y/o in entire MIMIC 3 database whose data was recorded by metavision data recorder?

Tags: mimic-iii

Try this code:

```
SELECT ie.subject_id, ie.hadm_id, ie.icustay_id,
    ie.intime, ie.outtime,
    ROUND((cast(ie.intime as date) - cast(pat.dob as date))/365.242, 2) AS age
FROM mimiciii.icustays ie
INNER JOIN mimiciii.patients pat
ON ie.subject_id = pat.subject_id
WHERE
ie.DBSOURCE = 'metavision'
```

all adults... why  ?
did I do mistake ?

Comment: This results in one record? What if you try something like `WHERE
ie.DBSOURCE like '%metavis%'`?

Comment: Is pat.dob always filled? What happens if it is not?

Comment: Good thought about like but the code still returns more than 15000 patients without the age condition applied - so doubt it is this.

Comment: It results in one record if you add age less than 16 condition

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, MIMIC-III only contains data pertaining to adults (or adolescents treated medically as adults). There are a few records of neonates from childbirths, but it is not the main focus of the database.

If you run this:

```
SELECT * from 
(
    SELECT ie.subject_id, ie.hadm_id, ie.icustay_id,
    ie.intime, ie.outtime,
    ROUND((cast(ie.intime as date) - cast(pat.dob as date))/365.242, 2) AS age
    FROM mimiciii.icustays ie
    INNER JOIN mimiciii.patients pat
    ON ie.subject_id = pat.subject_id
    WHERE ie.DBSOURCE = 'metavision'
) as A
WHERE age < 16
```

you will get 3 results, such as

```
subject_id hadm_id icustay_id intime              outtime             age
32035      113114  269627     2159-02-15 21:01:05 2159-02-16 19:16:36 15.05
```

These are ALL the subjects under 16 years of age whose data was collected using the Metavision system. If you include the CareVue system, you will get 9 results in total.